# how to pass a variables in to the tasks in ansible

Tags: ansible

i have a variable file , how can i call to that variable file in to the tasks

```
task:
  shell: mkdir test
  include_file: 
    vars.yml
```

How to pass a file in to the tasks using ansible play book

Comment: what do you want to do ? Is this what you want https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You use `vars_files` like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    vars.yml
  tasks:
    - shell: "echo var={{var}}"
```

or `include_vars`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
       file: vars.yml
    - shell: "echo var={{var}}"
```

Comment: Fair enough.  I updated answer and tested them this time instead of trying my luck with applying the docs blindly.